# how to get json value from sub array from main array

Tags: android, json

Iam stuck on getting array with options
My json looks like this,

```
 {
    "data": [{
        "id": "36",
        "combo_items": {
            "type": "",
            "combo": [""]
        }
    }, {
        "id": "14",
        "combo_items": {
            "type": "combo",
            "combo": [{
                "id": "12",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "id": "15",
                "name": "test"
            }]
        }
    },
    }]}
```

I already tried...
like these

```
            try {

                JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++)
                {
                    jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                    String id = jo.getString("id");

                    JSONObject combo_items = jo.getJSONObject("combo_items");
                    String combo_type = combo_items.getString("type");

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray =  combo_items.getJSONArray("combo");
                        for (int ii =0; ii<jsonArray.length(); ii++){
                            jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(ii);
                            String combo_id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                            String combo_name=jsonObject.getString("name");

                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

how to get json object from inside json array, i tried method shows some errors
*string canot be cast to jsonobject*
Please help.

Comment: Is this JSON or Gson from where you are getting this response

Comment: json,from our php side

Comment: You are getting error from this line "combo": [""]  its a array of string not josn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `opt` instead of `get` and check for null.

```
try {

    JSONArray ja = response.optJSONArray("data");

    if (ja == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jo = ja.optJSONObject(i);

        if (jo == null) {
            continue;
        }

        String id = jo.optString("id");

        JSONObject combo_items = jo.optJSONObject("combo_items");
        String combo_type = combo_items.optString("type");

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = combo_items.optJSONArray("combo");
            if (jsonArray != null) {
                for (int ii = 0; ii < jsonArray.length(); ii++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(ii);
                    if (jsonObject == null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String combo_id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                    String combo_name = jsonObject.getString("name");

                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {

}
```